# NodeJs. Sequelize. Unsupported time zone specified undefined

Tags: mysql, node.js, centos

С самого начала проект работал, все было хорошо, и в 1 момент при перезапуске получаю такую ошибку

```
    RangeError: Unsupported time zone specified undefined
    at new DateTimeFormat (native)
    at Date.toLocaleTimeString (native)
    at retryAsPromised (/var/www/test_v2/node_modules/retry-as-promised/index.js:58:91)
    at Promise.try (/var/www/test_v2/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:619:30)
    at tryCatcher (/var/www/test_v2/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Function.Promise.attempt.Promise.try (/var/www/test_v2/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/method.js:39:29)
    at Sequelize.query (/var/www/test_v2/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:576:23)
    at promise.then (/var/www/test_v2/node_modules/sequelize/lib/query-interface.js:236:46)
    at tryCatcher (/var/www/test_v2/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/var/www/test_v2/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:517:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/var/www/test_v2/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:574:18)
    at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (/var/www/test_v2/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:611:10)
    at _drainQueueStep (/var/www/test_v2/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:142:12)
    at _drainQueue (/var/www/test_v2/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (/var/www/test_v2/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/var/www/test_v2/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
    at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:126:23) 'Something went wrong with the Database Update!'
(node:22620) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError: Unsupported time zone specified undefined
    at new DateTimeFormat (native)
    at Date.toLocaleTimeString (native)
    at retryAsPromised (/var/www/test_v2/node_modules/retry-as-promised/index.js:58:91)
    at Promise.try (/var/www/test_v2/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:619:30)
    at tryCatcher (/var/www/test_v2/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Function.Promise.attempt.Promise.try (/var/www/test_v2/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/method.js:39:29)
    at Sequelize.query (/var/www/test_v2/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:576:23)
    at QueryInterface.select (/var/www/test_v2/node_modules/sequelize/lib/query-interface.js:1120:27)
    at Promise.try.then.then.then (/var/www/test_v2/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1749:34)
    at tryCatcher (/var/www/test_v2/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/var/www/test_v2/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:517:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/var/www/test_v2/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:574:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/var/www/test_v2/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:619:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/var/www/test_v2/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:699:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (/var/www/test_v2/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
    at _drainQueue (/var/www/test_v2/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (/var/www/test_v2/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/var/www/test_v2/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
    at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:126:23)
(node:22620) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:22620) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:22620) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError: Unsupported time zone specified undefined
```

у меня CentOS 6, такой конфиг:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, 

    {
        dialect: "mysql"
    });
```

локально на windows10 все работает,
попробовал настроить поставить еще: `timezone: '+00:00'`,
по форумам искал, попробовал все что возможно, ничего не помогает.
Помогите пожалуйста кто может.

Comment: Куда проект деплоешь?

Comment: сервер на centos 6

Comment: Если работает локально, мне кажется что ты в файле `package.json` не все пакеты указал на `centos 6`. Проверь файл `package.json` на  `centos 6`.

Comment: Пакеты указаны все правильно, все обновления закидываются через git, и в конце концов, проект перестал работать  просто при перезагрузке, новых библиотек я не подключал при этом

Answer (score 0):

Ответ простой, надо было зайти под `sudo -s` и запустить, не знаю почему так, возможно система обновилась или что еще случилось но без `sudo -s` больше не запускается